# Date conversion datenum datestr

Tags: matlab, date

I've processed my data by `datenum(DATE(xy), 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')`  and when I tried to convert it back to the date formate by `datestr(DATE(xy), 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')` I've got different date. The original date was *8.4.2013  4:12:31* and the converted is *04-Oct-2013 04:12:31*
 Any idea, where is the error?
Thanks Tomas

Comment: Looks like `datestr` produces a string with the correct format. How did you manage to apply `datenum` on "8.4.2013" using the "dd-mmm-yyyy" format anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the format of the input-date? Is it `08-04-2013 04:12:31`? If it is given as `8.4.2013 4:12:31` your second input to datenum is incorrect. You specify the format: `'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')`, while your input seems to be `8.4.2013 4:12:31`.

Try:

```
datenum(DATE(xy), 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```